Seems Puppeteer is preventing my express route handler on ubuntu linux from sending a response but it sends on my windows local machine
The code I will paste below runs on my local machine but when on my ubuntu vps server it runs also which i verified by logs to the console that it created the f object at the bottom but then it failed to send a response. Other route handlers are working fine just this one that's working with PUPPETEER. Is there anyway to force this route handler to send a response or a configuration to solve this issue on vps enviroment?
const Facebook = require("../models/facebookModel");
const Sent = require("../models/sentModel");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

exports.createFacebook = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { appState, userProfileLink, friendProfileLink, concurrencyLevel } =
      req.body;
    // Modify the cookies to have valid sameSite values
    const cookie = JSON.parse(appState);
    const modifiedCookies = cookie.map((cookie) => {
      if (cookie.sameSite && typeof cookie.sameSite === "string") {
        switch (cookie.sameSite.toLowerCase()) {
          case "lax":
          case "strict":
          case "none":
            cookie.sameSite =
              cookie.sameSite.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
              cookie.sameSite.slice(1).toLowerCase();
            break;
          default:
            cookie.sameSite = "None"; // Set to 'None' if the value is not recognized
        }
      } else {
        cookie.sameSite = "None"; // Default to 'None' if sameSite is not set or null
      }
      return cookie;
    });

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: ["--start-maximized", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1400, height: 900 });

    await page.goto("https://facebook.com", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
      timeout: 0,
    });

    await page.setCookie(...modifiedCookies);

    const friendListUrl = friendProfileLink.includes("=")
      ? friendProfileLink + "&sk=friends"
      : friendProfileLink + "/friends";

    await page.goto(friendListUrl, {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
      timeout: 0,
    });

    // Function to scroll the page to the bottom
    async function scrollPageToBottom() {
      await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let totalHeight = 0;
          const distance = 100;
          const scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
            const scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
            window.scrollBy(0, distance);
            totalHeight += distance;

            if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
              clearInterval(scrollInterval);
              resolve();
            }
          }, 100); // Adjust the interval as needed
        });
      });
    }

    // Scroll the page to the bottom
    await scrollPageToBottom();

    const friendsListSelector = ".x1iyjqo2.x1pi30zi";

    await page.waitForSelector(friendsListSelector, { timeout: 0 });
    const friendsListLinks = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
      const friendsDiv = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      const allProfileLinks = Array.from(friendsDiv).map((el) => {
        const firstChild = el.querySelector(":first-child");
        const link = firstChild.querySelector("a");
        const profileName = firstChild.innerText;
        const profileObj = {
          name: profileName,
          link: link ? link.href : "",
        };
        return profileObj;
      });
      if (allProfileLinks.length > 0) {
        return allProfileLinks;
      }
      return null;
    }, friendsListSelector);

    const filteredFriendsList = friendsListLinks.filter(
      (el) =>
        el.link !== "" &&
        !el.link.includes("photo") &&
        el.link !== userProfileLink
    );

    const pages = await Promise.all(
      Array(+concurrencyLevel)
        .fill()
        .map(() => browser.newPage())
    );
    await Promise.all(
      pages.map((page) => page.setViewport({ width: 1400, height: 900 }))
    );

    const chunks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < filteredFriendsList.length; i += +concurrencyLevel) {
      chunks.push(filteredFriendsList.slice(i, i + +concurrencyLevel));
    }

    const result = [];
    for (const chunk of chunks) {
      const promises = chunk.map((list, index) => {
        const page = pages[index];
        return (async () => {
          const lastFourChars = list.link.slice(-15);
          const isnumber = /^\d{15}$/.test(lastFourChars);
          const link = isnumber
            ? `${list.link}&sk=about_overview`
            : `${list.link}/about_overview`;

          await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 0 });

          const relationshipStatus = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const statuses = [
              "Single",
              "Married",
              "In a relationship",
              "Engaged",
              "In a domestic partnership",
              "In a civil partnership",
              "In an open relationship",
              "It's complicated",
              "Separated",
              "Divorced",
              "Widowed",
              "No relationship info to show",
            ];

            let span;
            // Find all spans that contain the current status
            const spans = document.querySelectorAll(`span`);
            // Loop through each status and attempt to find the corresponding span element
            for (const status of statuses) {
              // Iterate over the found spans
              spans.forEach((spanElement) => {
                if (spanElement.innerText === status) {
                  // If the text content matches the current status, set the variable and break the loop
                  span = spanElement;
                  return;
                }
              });
              if (span) {
                break; // Stop the loop if a matching span is found
              }
            }
            const statusElement = span;
            return statusElement ? statusElement.innerText : null;
          });

          await page.goto(
            isnumber
              ? `${list.link}&sk=about_contact_and_basic_info`
              : `${list.link}/about_contact_and_basic_info`,
            { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 0 }
          );

          const genderValue = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const genders = ["Male", "Female"];
            let span;
            // Find all spans that contain the current status
            const spans = document.querySelectorAll(`span`);

            // Loop through each status and attempt to find the corresponding span element
            for (const status of genders) {
              // Iterate over the found spans
              spans.forEach((spanElement) => {
                if (spanElement.innerText === status) {
                  // If the text content matches the current status, set the variable and break the loop
                  span = spanElement;
                  return;
                }
              });
              if (span) {
                break; // Stop the loop if a matching span is found
              }
            }

            const genderElement = span;
            return genderElement ? genderElement.innerText : null;
          });

          const userId = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let userId = null;

            // Select all script tags
            const scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script");
            scripts.forEach((script) => {
              const text = script.textContent || script.innerText;
              // Look for a pattern that matches the user ID
              const match = text.match(/"userID":"(\d+)"/);
              if (match) {
                userId = match[1];
              }
            });

            return userId;
          });

          const profileObj = {
            name: list.name,
            link: userId
              ? `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=${userId}`
              : list.link,
            gender: genderValue,
            relationshipStatus,
          };

          return profileObj;
        })();
      });

      result.push(...(await Promise.all(promises)));
    }

    const cleanedResult = result.map((pro) => {
      const uid = pro.link.includes("=")
        ? pro.link.split("=")[1]
        : pro.link.split(".com/")[1];

      return {
        full_name: pro.name,
        uid,
        relationshipStatus: pro.relationshipStatus,
        gender: pro.gender,
      };
    });

    const cleanedResultFiltered = cleanedResult.filter(
      (el) => el.gender !== null
    );

    await browser.close();
    //..........................................................................

    const sent = await Sent.findOne({ account: req.account._id });
    if (!sent) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        status: "fail",
        message: "old data not found",
      });
    }
    const oldData = sent.usernames;

    const oldDataUids = new Set(oldData);

    const all = cleanedResult.filter((el) => !oldDataUids.has(el.uid));
    const singleMales = cleanedResultFiltered.filter(
      (el) =>
        !oldDataUids.has(el.uid) &&
        el.gender === "Male" &&
        (el.relationshipStatus === "Single" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === null ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "It's complicated" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Widowed" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Divorced" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Separated" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "No relationship info to show")
    );

    const singleFemales = cleanedResultFiltered.filter(
      (el) =>
        !oldDataUids.has(el.uid) &&
        el.gender === "Female" &&
        (el.relationshipStatus === "Single" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === null ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "It's complicated" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Widowed" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Divorced" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Separated" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "No relationship info to show")
    );

    const marriedMales = cleanedResultFiltered.filter(
      (el) =>
        !oldDataUids.has(el.uid) &&
        el.gender === "Male" &&
        (el.relationshipStatus === "Married" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In a relationship" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Engaged" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In a domestic partnership" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In a civil partnership" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In an open relationship")
    );

    const marriedFemales = cleanedResultFiltered.filter(
      (el) =>
        !oldDataUids.has(el.uid) &&
        el.gender === "Female" &&
        (el.relationshipStatus === "Married" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In a relationship" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "Engaged" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In a domestic partnership" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In a civil partnership" ||
          el.relationshipStatus === "In an open relationship")
    );

    let usernames;
    if (req.body.category === "Single males") {
      usernames = singleMales;
    } else if (req.body.category === "Single females") {
      usernames = singleFemales;
    } else if (req.body.category === "Married males") {
      usernames = marriedMales;
    } else if (req.body.category === "Married females") {
      usernames = marriedFemales;
    } else {
      usernames = all;
    }

    req.body.appState = modifiedCookies;
    req.body.messages = JSON.parse(req.body.messages);

    const facebook = await Facebook.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      messages: req.body.messages,
      usernamesCounter: 0,
      messagesCounter: 0,
      appState: req.body.appState,
      status: true,
      usernames: usernames,
      account: req.account._id,
      totalUids: usernames.length,
    });

    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      message: `Facebook object created successfully`,
      data: {
        facebook,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: err.message,
      error: err,
    });
  }
};


I have installed all the necessary programs to enable puppeteer run on ubuntu but just not getting the response

There's a lot of code here. Can you provide a minimal example and system details necessary to reproduce? Are there any errors, or which line does the request handler get hung up on? Thanks.

I don’t think the code is the problem. It runs smoothly on my local machine but hangs on the response as the Facebook object is created at the end and saved to the database. This has to be a problem with Ubuntu vps server configuration. I just don’t get a response!!

If the code isn't the problem, then I would still minimize it all the way down to the simplest failing example (a few lines of complete, runnable code--just enough to cause the failure), and then explain exactly how you're setting up the VPS server configuration so they can repro the issue. This will help people answer, but right now you have 360 lines of code that is pretty impenetrable. If the response is all that's failing, it sounds like Puppeteer may not even be a factor--it could be a pure Express issue. In that case, I'd strip out all Puppeteer logic here and remove the tag.

What you can do is initialize  puppeteer in a route handler and just visit a page, close the browser and try to send a response in the end. I am using hostinger vps server Ubuntu 20.0 and I did strip out the puppeteer logic and the handler sent a response

Go ahead and [edit] your question with that minimal failing code and your server details. I'm still seeing 360 lines of code, a major distraction from anyone answering this, if it's mostly unrelated to the core issue you're asking about. Thanks.

I am hoping someone would figure out why puppeteer maybe blocking just the response

I know you want that, and I'm helping you get there by making your question more approachable. I don't have a VPS at the moment so I can't reproduce the issue, but hopefully someone else can.

I can give you access to my VPS if you can figure this issue out
